# How to split a directory of files into sub-directories

Tags: bash, osx

I have a directory full of files similar to these:

```
3260_661901_2008-2008.dat
3260_661901_2009-2009.dat
3260_661901_2010-2010.dat
3260_661901_2011-2011.dat
3260_661901_por-1998.dat
3260_662336_1999-1999.dat
3260_662336_2000-2000.dat
3260_662336_2001-2001.dat
3260_662336_2002-2002.dat
```

I would like to split off the files into directories names after the 6th and 7th character in the filename like this:

```
66/3260_661901_2008-2008.dat
66/3260_661901_2009-2009.dat
66/3260_661901_2010-2010.dat
66/3260_661901_2011-2011.dat
67/3260_671901_por-1998.dat
67/3260_672336_1999-1999.dat
67/3260_672336_2000-2000.dat
88/3260_882336_2001-2001.dat
88/3260_882336_2002-2002.dat
```

Is there a quick one liner command I can use to create the subdirectories and move the files into them?

I should mention the directory has over 33k files in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
ls |  awk '{d=substr($0,6,2) ; printf "mkdir %s ; mv %s %s\n",d,$1,d }' | bash
```

- in this case, you can use ls result as input.
- you'll get error message as dir exists after first `mkdir`, to get rid use :

  ```
  awk '{d=substr($0,6,2) ; printf "test -d %s || mkdir %s ; mv %s %s\n",d,d,$1,d }'
  ```

Comment: use `mkdir -p` to avoid an error msg.

Comment: no way !! I like unnecessary complexity

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are using `bash` you could run

```
for f in *.dat; do mkdir -p "${f:5:2}"; mv "$f" "${f:5:2}/"; done
```

or (if there are too many files for `for f in *.dat` to work)

```
while read f; do mkdir -p "${f:5:2}"; mv "$f" "${f:5:2}/"; done < ls
```