# How to organize files in main directory into smaller amount of files in sub-directories

Tags: bash, ksh

I have a directory of 150 files that I wanted split into sub-directories of 25 files each: 1-25 into dir1, 26-50 into dir2, and so on.  How can I accomplish this?

```
dir1/fre_4_g2_c3654214.h3

dir1/fre_4_g2_c0585433.h3

dir1/fre_4_g2_c3565415.h3
```

... and so on

and what I'd want to do is

```
dir1/fre_4_g2_c3654214.h3

dir2/fre_4_g2_c0585433.h3

dir3/fre_4_g2_c3565415.h3
```

Comment: You should tell us what you already tried!

Comment: I looked at this post:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/228494/how-to-split-a-directory-of-files-into-sub-directories

but was unable to figure out how to use it for what I'm doing.  Specifically, I tried

    for f in *.dat; do mkdir -p "${f:5:2}"; mv "$f" "${f:5:2}/"; done

and got 1 directory with 4 files and another with over 100

Comment: Add some examples of your file names?  Are they all similarly named?  Do they have file extensions of some sort?  etc

Comment: Yes, they're all similarly named and have the same extension

Comment: notice how in the first 3 lines that the parent directory is dir1 and the bottom 3 examples the parent directory is different for each file?

Comment: Do your 150 files need to be partitioned into specific groups, or is it just any 25 per subdirectory?

Answer (score 1):

This will sort the files alphanumerically and move the first 25 files into subdirectory `dir0`, the next 25 into `dir1`, etc., until all files are moved:

```
 n=0; for f in *; do d="dir$((n++ / 25))"; mkdir -p "$d"; mv -- "$f" "$d/$f"; done
```

For those who prefer their commands spread over multiple lines:

```
n=0
for f in *
do
    d="dir$((n++ / 25))"
    mkdir -p "$d"
    mv -- "$f" "$d/$f"
done
```

This will work under either `ksh` or `bash`.

Comment: Problem Solved.